# Sending GET or POST request via Form in Android

Tags: android, post, get

I want to create a form in android and send the data via GET or POST to my webhook .How do I do it?

Comment: Consider using Retrofit 2. https://github.com/square/retrofit

Answer (score 1):

using **Retrofit** library makes the job easy and manages almost eveything for you. just google about it. there's like a million of useful tutorials.

Answer (score -1):

Use a webview, write the code the same way you would in html but as a string or in an asset file (set the webview layout using the html code) and use AsyncTask or a threadPool to make the network calls.

https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/run-code.html

read dev docs

Comment: Writing code to put it in a webview is not really "Android development". You're basically just working around the problem, providing a poor user experience, combined with a hardly maintanable solution.

Comment: U might be surprised how many android apps do things like that, especially if they have a mobile web site that has the same functionality. Im not saying I recommend doing it that way but it seemed like thats what he wanted to do. If I was designing/writing it I would make the 'form' a layout and use a thread pool or task/runnable to make the network calls. https://gist.github.com/ValeFCF/4347381

Comment: I know how many Android app do this... But if you do not recommend doing it that way and thinks that not a good way to develop it, then you should not write it down on the Internet ;-) If you want to stop a bad practice to be used, stop the spread it :) Also, for your network calls, check Retrofit, you will love to never have to use `AsyncTask` anymore

Comment: I didn't mean to recommend this as an ideal technique but it seems like Pradyumna would be more familiar working this way given the terms used. I  agree it's not exactly the 'Android' way of doing things and definitely not the best way or how I would do it. I also suggested using a threadPool and reading the android dev docs if you want to put the time in to learn how to do it right. But by the way this question was asked seems like they wanted a quick solution and I think I provided that. @mithrop I didn't use the words I recommend you do it this way, I was just saying you can do it this w